# UIPickerView is not removed when row selected

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UIPickerView that appears when a textfield is selected:

```
-(void) showPicker
{
    [self.genere resignFirstResponder];
    pickerGenero = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,215,320,0)];

    pickerGenero.delegate = self;
    pickerGenero.dataSource = self;
    pickerGenero.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;    

    [self.parentViewController.tabBarController.view addSubview:pickerGenero];  
    pickerGenero=nil; 
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component 
{
    return [genreArray count];
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    return 1;  
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    self.genere.text =[genreArray objectAtIndex:row];
    [self.pickerGenero removeFromSuperview];


}
```

But is not removed when a row is selected. Textfield is updated with the selected value, but the picker view is not removed. I've tried to use as a trial .sethideen=True but it doesn't work, too.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your's is not the correct way of coding. When you click the textField you just hide the keyboard by using `resignFirstResponder` and invoking `pickerView`.Instead of doing like that, you have to add your `pickerView` as `inputView` for `genere` textField. and try this code then

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    self.genere.text =[genreArray objectAtIndex:row];
    [genere resignFirstResponder];

}
```